# Angular 6: Multiple configurations (twas environments)

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular6

Trying to get angular-cli to recognise multiple configurations in `angular.json`

```
C:\_dev\myapp>ng serve --configuration development
Configuration 'development' could not be found in project 'myapp'.
Error: Configuration 'development' could not be found in project 'myapp'.
```

The snippet being:

```
    "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.production.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true
        },
        "development": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.development.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": false,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": true,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": true,
          "aot": false,
          "extractLicenses": false,
          "vendorChunk": true,
          "buildOptimizer": false
        }
      }
```

`src/environments/environment.development.ts` does exist

```
ng serve --configuration production
```

works fine

Answer (score 65, accepted):

There is a `configurations` entry in the `build` and in the `serve` section of the *angular.json* file. The serve part needs to know about your custom configuration as well. Assuming your configuration name is **debug**, add it to the serve section as follows

```json
"projects": {
  "myApp": {
     [...]
     "architect": {
       "build": {
         [...]
         "configurations": {
           "production": { [...] },
           "debug": { [...] }
         }
       },
       "serve": {
         [...]
         "configurations": {
           "production": {
             "browserTarget": "myApp:build:production"
           },
           "debug": {
             "browserTarget": "myApp:build:debug"
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Don't forget to adjust `myApp` to your projects name equal to the direct child of the `project` section in your *angular.json*. Also both `debug`'s should match your configuration in `build` section.

Then serve with

```
ng serve --configuration=debug
```

Comment: thanks ! I was putting everything under build and nothing under serve. Feel so dumm...

Comment: Note that all fields in `"options"` (here just `"browserTarget"`, but you may have others such as `"serverTarget"`) should be specified in both options and each configuration

Answer (score -6):

For Angular 2 - 5 refer the article for step by step solution for using [Multiple Environment in angular](https://medium.com/@onlyyprasanth/how-to-manage-multiple-environments-with-angular-cli-angular-2-to-5-aa68d557fa77)

For Angular 6 use `ng serve --configuration=dev`

> Note: Refer the same article for angular 6 as well. But wherever you find `--env` instead use `--configuration`. That's works well for angular 6.